# Pulling records with same value in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sub-table like the following. It contains 14 fields of true/false values, and the Status field is 0 if all values for Status 1-14 is false.

| DCID | Status | Status1 | Status2 | Status3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | false | false | false |
| 2 | 1 | false | true | false |
| 3 | 1 | true | true | false |

I need to pull an export from the table that only contains one field stating which Status column has a true, or provide a placeholder value if there are multiple trues, like below

| ID | StatusNew |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 2 | Status2 |
| 3 | Multiple |

I've been working in SQL Fiddle and keep getting hit with `ORA-00905: missing keyword` but I'm also thinking there is probably a more efficient way to pull this export. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f7763/4

Comment: Happens to the best of us. You forgot your "ON t1.dcid = t2.dcid" joining to the subquery.

Comment: Then you probably want a DISTINCT to shore up those dups for multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT dcid,
       CASE status1 + status2 + status3 + status4
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'None'
       WHEN 1
       THEN COALESCE(
              CASE status1 WHEN 1 THEN 'status1' END,
              CASE status2 WHEN 1 THEN 'status2' END,
              CASE status3 WHEN 1 THEN 'status3' END,
              CASE status4 WHEN 1 THEN 'status4' END
            )
       ELSE 'Multiple'
       END AS status_new
FROM   yourtable;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE yourtable(dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DCID | STATUS_NEW |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | status1 |
| 2 | None |
| 3 | Multiple |
| 4 | status2 |
| 5 | None |
| 6 | Multiple |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mwj_vwaW)

Comment: Thank you! All the answers to this question were very helpful but this is the one that worked best for the dataset in practice. One follow up question though: I have a similar dataset I need to pull a similar report on but those status fields use TRUE/FALSE instead of 1/0. How would that be approached?

Comment: @d.sweigart You can use a `CASE` expression or `DECODE` to convert the value from TRUE/FALSE back to a number - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IAo5JX17)

Answer (score 0):

These both match with your sample data, where None is included. Your fiddle excludes none. Easy tweak either way.

What you did in the fiddle joining to a subquery is also fine, just don't forget your join condition "ON t1.dcid = t2.dcid".

Option 1: This is mostly for fun. If you really, really, don't want to unpivot. This may outperform unpivot because it doesn't create any new rows in an intermediate step. But it has the major downsides of being absurd, and if your data model ever changes to add a new status someone needs to remember to change this logic. That should always be avoided if possible.

Option 2: Very minor tweak to your original query. Uses an in-line correlated subquery, but your way is also perfectly good.

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (dcid varchar2(1), stat varchar2(1), status1 int, status2 int, status3 int, status4 int)
;


INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    INTO yourtable (dcid, stat, status1, status2, status3, status4)
         VALUES (6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

-- Option 1:

select dcid,
       case when regexp_count(delimited_trues,'-') is null then 'None'
            when regexp_count(delimited_trues,'-') = 1 then replace(delimited_trues, '-','')
            else 'M'
        end as status_new
  from (
        select dcid,
               case when status1 = 1 then 'status1-' else '' end
                 || 
               case when status2 = 1then 'status2-' else '' end
                 || 
               case when status3 = 1then 'status3-' else '' end
                 || 
               case when status4 = 1then 'status4-' else '' end as delimited_trues
          from yourtable
       );

-- Option 2:
with d_status as (
  select
    dcid
    ,status_t
    ,status_c
  from yourtable
  unpivot exclude nulls (
    status_c
    for status_t
    in (
      status1
      ,status2
      ,status3
      ,status4
      )
    )
  )
select dcid,
       case when sum(status_c) = 0 then 'None'
            when sum(status_c) > 1 then 'M'
            when sum(status_c) = 1 then 
                    ( select status_t
                        from d_status t2
                       where t1.dcid = t2.dcid
                         and t2.status_c = 1
                    )
        end
  from d_status t1
 group
    by dcid
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to concatenate the Status1 through StatusN columns. Use INSTR to find the first "1" in the concatenated value. SUM all of the StatusN columns to get the total number of true values. Finally, decode the SUM to determine the new status.

```sql
WITH yourtable(DCID, Status, Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4)
AS
(
    SELECT 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION 
    SELECT 6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT dcid "ID"
      ,DECODE(SUM(Status1 + Status2 + Status3 + Status4)
             ,0, 'None'
             ,1, 'Status' || INSTR(Status1 || Status2 || Status3 || Status4, '1')
            ,'Multiple') "NewStatus"
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY dcid, Status1 || Status2 || Status3 || Status4
ORDER BY dcid
```

| ID | NewStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Status1 |
| 2 | None |
| 3 | Multiple |
| 4 | Status2 |
| 5 | None |
| 6 | Multiple |